# AES encryption using the Argon2 hash of a passcode, instead of the passcode directly - does it improve security?

Tags: security, encryption

Say I want to encrypt a file `mydata.txt` using a hard to guess password such as `Passw0rd!`, but I am concerned the end-user might misunderstand what a hard to guess password is and may inadvertently or unknowingly use a password less secure than desired for the application.

Can I use Argon2 to "make" even easy password hard to guess for AES (or similar) encryption? Here is how I picture this to happen.

1. I have a file `mydata.txt`, then the user supplies a secret string `pass14988`.
2. My application uses Argon2 to hash the pasword securely `hash = Argon2("Passw0rd!")`.
3. My application uses `hash` has the password to AES.
4. For decryption, it follows that the encryption file must always include a copy of the salt and Argon2 settings (but obviously not the unique hash).

Now any malicious user attempting to decrypt the file will have to run Argon2 on each guess in addition to the difficulty inherent to AES.

Comment: You are looking for "key stretching" - look it up, don't invent your own.

Comment: argon2 is a password hashing function, there is no point to hashing a file with it.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk ops, corrected!

Comment: In your sample, you're hashing what we call a "magic string", but I would then ask what function is the secret string you specify in #1 serving? It seems to be doing nothing. If your intent is to use "Passw0rd!" as a salt, you're using it wrong... a salt is supposed to turn a deterministic function into a PRF (psuedorandom function) to make lookup attacks against the password harder. Just hash the user's input secret with a salt, specify whatever salt length and round/cost NIST says is minimum, use the output of the hash as the AES key. Done!

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Argon2 is a [Key Derivation Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) (KDF), meaning it is meant exactly for this purpose.

AES requires a very specific key size (a 128-bit key is required for AES-128, a 256-bit key for AES-256, etc). The key for AES must be the correct size for the encryption algorithm to run correctly. You cannot use the raw password as the key for AES-256 unless the password is *exactly* 256-bits (32 characters on practically all computers). Instead, the password should be hashed using a KDF to produce the encryption key for AES (note that even a 32 character password for AES-256 ought to be run through the KDF to give it the proper entropy; most passwords are limited to a subset of the 256 possible bit combos available in a single byte and thus have lower entropy than an encryption key should).

The KDF should, as you likely already know, be slow/resource intensive to compute so that brute forcing the password isn't significantly faster than just brute forcing the derived key.

Your scheme sounds correct to me. Provided the salt and other hashing parameters, one could hash a provided password to derive the encryption key and decrypt the data. However, it is important to note that an easy-to-guess password is still easy to guess even when using a KDF. No amount of hashing or stretching will make `Passw0rd!` a good password.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of Argon2 is to stretch passwords. You don't need to invent a new way to use it to do that. Just use it as it's designed to be used. Given your description, the correct approach is:

- The user supplies a password (`pass14988`)
- The application generates a random 8 byte salt
- The application hashes the password and salt: `hash = Argon2(password: "pass14988", salt: salt)`
- Use hash as the key for AES (AES uses keys, not passwords)
- Store the salt and the Argon2 settings (if needed) with the encrypted data

There's no reason to mix in any hard-coded string (what I assume `Passw0rd` represents). Just use Argon2 on the user-supplied password, along with a random salt.